# How to install Wordpress with WHM UAPI with custom name and password?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel, whm

I want to install Wordpress site using WHM UAPI programatically.
But the admin name is using default account's user name.

I had successfully install a Wordpress in Wordpress Toolkit with
`https://example.com:2087/json-api/uapi_cpanel?api.version=1&cpanel.function=create&cpanel.module=WordPressSite&cpanel.user=username`.

I want to create a custom admin name like "admin_sample" and create a custom password.

Comment: i have softaculous and here is the API - https://www.softaculous.com/docs/api/api/#php-2

Comment: @Snuffy Thank your for you help but unfortunately I don't have softaculous

Comment: I dont think uapi supports parameters - https://api.docs.cpanel.net/openapi/cpanel/operation/WordPressSite::create/ . Maybe ask in the forum ?

Comment: @Snuffy Thank you for help, UAPI doesn't support parameters (I asked in the forum). At the end I try to call [WP Toolkit API](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/wp-toolkit-6-0-release-now-available/) and managed to installed with custom name and password.